# How to upload an existing .ipa-file with In-App-Purchases to ituneconnect without XCode

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, ipa

For some speficic reasons I do not want to explain here, I want to upload an existing .ipa-file with In-App-Purchases to ituneconnect without XCode.

Is this possible? If yes, how? Or how can I upload an existing .ipa-file using XCode 7.x.x?

Note: I understand that a tool called 'Application Loader' exists. Hovever I believe that In-App-Purchases need to be added manually this way, which is not needed in my case...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. Is it your Application with your own code? Because you need to sign your applications with your own profile. Each application has it own set of certificates to make uploading to iTunes connect possible.

Comment: Then if you compiled it with the right code signing, you should be able to upload it using application loader.